# Best way to initialize form data on menu item selection in Spring MVC with JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

I am having some menu items which are calling .jsp files, my menu related code is like:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">menu2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu ">
        <a href="drop1.jsp" class="dropdown-item">drop1</a>
        <a href="drop2.jsp" class="dropdown-item">drop2</a>
        <a href="drop3.jsp" class="dropdown-item">drop3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Requirement:** [1] When user select any menu item For example: 'drop1' I want to fetch some data from the database and those fetched data I want to display in drop1.jsp. 
**Note:** I am using spring security5.3.2, JSP, Java8 and Spring 5.2.6

Comment: I am able to achieve the 2nd requirement by using  this concept  But I am  still struggling with my 1st requirement                                                              @RequestMapping("/search")
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam String searchId) {  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Ajax which is calling spring controller on page load, for example:
**In my jsp page:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "categories",
        success: function(data){
            var slctcat=$('#selectdCategory'), option="";
            slctcat.empty();
            option= option + "<option value=''>- Select Catagory -</option>";
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                option = option + "<option value='"+data[i].categoryId + "'>"+data[i].categoryName + "</option>";
            }
            slctcat.append(option);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

And in my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/categories")
public @ResponseBody  List<ProductCategoriesEntity> getAllCategories() {
    productCategories= productCategoriesService.getAllProductCategories();
 return productCategories;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not getting your 1st requirement.

About 2nd you can use a simple Ajax call to the controller and return the response msg on the same page,  the page will not get refresh and you will be on the same page with all stufs done in background.

Comment: The first requirement is when user select any  menu item For example: 'drop1' I want to fetch some data from the database and those fetched data I want to display in drop1.jsp